# Word VBA Macro to Export Sections as PDF

Tags: vba, ms-word

**Background**: I currently have a document that is broken up into separate sections by section breaks in Word. I have a macro to **print** pdf's of the sections to a users chosen directory and a macro to **export** static pages as pdf's. I've entered the page numbers in the **export** macro for the time being because the save function works a lot faster than the print as pdf function. But I would like to have the macro export sections as pdfs with page numbers that can change.

**Note**: Section pages can change depending on the work I am doing on my master file, so using static page numbers in my macro is only temporary solution. Resolving this is really important for me.

What I Have So Far (This is the **export** macro):

```
Sub PLANv()
'
' PLANv Macro
'
'
Dim strName As String

strName = InputBox(Prompt:="Save To:", Title:="Save file to:", _
Default:="C:\Users\PRESTONAVH\Desktop\Task Order Files\")

If strName = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub
Else

End If

ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
    strName & "PLAN.pdf", _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
    wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportFromTo, From:=3, To:=4, Item:= _
    wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=False, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
End Sub
```

**What I Would Like to Have**:

It seems that my macro that exports as a PDF does not allow me to put the sections in the range field, I've tried and it always gives me an error message. I currently have the static page range in there (3-4).  I was thinking that maybe there there is some code I could enter before that, that would return the starting page number and ending page number of the section I'm exporting. Then I could assign a string to whatever is returned and then in the range function enter those strings as the page numbers?

I'm really not good at this stuff but have been going through lots of forums and trying to piece together what other people have suggested with no luck. There is probably a much easier solution, but as long as it works that would really be great. I've been trying to figure this out for some time now, but I've gone through too many forums and am a VBA super beginner.

If anyone would be able to help me out I would really appreciate it.

Thank You

Update:
I tried the export section code as recommended but my fields were erased in the exported documents and a blank page added. So I'm trying to use the section range to set the first and last integers of the export range. I can get intValue1 which gives me the last page of the section range. But I don't know how to get intValue2 for the first page of the section range. Below is what I added in between my save prompt and the export code.

```
Dim intValueR As Range
Dim intValue1 As Integer
Dim intValue2 As Integer
Set intValueR = ActiveDocument.Sections(3).Range
intValue1 = CStr(intValueR.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber))
intValue2 = ??
```

**(SOLVED)**
Hi everyone, thanks for helping me out, I have the final code that is working well for me now. Here's the code:

```
Dim strName As String

strName = InputBox(Prompt:="Save To:", Title:="Save file to:", _
Default:="C:\Users\PRESTONAVH\Desktop\Task Order Files\")

If strName = vbNullString Then
Exit Sub
Else

End If

Dim intValue1 As Integer
Dim intValue2 As Integer
intValue1 = 
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) + 1
intValue2 = 
ActiveDocument.Sections(2).Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)

ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
    strName & "PLAN.pdf", _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
    wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportFromTo, From:=intValue1, 
To:=intValue2, Item:= _
    wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=False, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
```

Comment: there is a problem with trying to export page numbers, because page numbers are dependent on the printed page size, margins etc. you may need to somehow specify a "dummy" printer that has a preset page and margin sizes.

Comment: I noticed this on another macro and it was using the default settings on whichever computer it was being run on. When we changed the default settings then the margins and page sizes came out properly. But the export function seems to be working better for our purposes at the moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I found a solution, it's really ugly but it works. Since I didn't know how to set the first part of the section range as an integer but I did know how to set the last part of the section range as an integer. I simply set the first part as the last part of the previous section's range plus 1.

The result is this bit of code:

```
Dim intValueR As Range
Dim intValueR2 As Range
Dim intValue1 As Integer
Dim intValue2 As Integer
Set intValueR = ActiveDocument.Sections(3).Range
Set intValueR2 = ActiveDocument.Sections(2).Range
intValue1 = CStr(intValueR.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber))
intValue2 = CStr(intValueR2.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)) + 1
```

If someone has a cleaner way of doing this, that would be fantastic. But if someone needs something like this, it's working for me.

Shout out to @TonyM and @jsotola!

Comment: NB: `Cstr` is unnecessary and potentially wrong overhead. It's casting an integer/long value to a string, which is then implicitly converted back to an integer (e.g., `intValue1 As Integer`, etc). Remove `Cstr` for sure.

Comment: @PrestonAVH, wrap section2page conversion in a function  `function sec2page(sec as integer) as integer`  `sec2page = ActiveDocument.Sections(sec).Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)` `end function`

Comment: @jsotoloa, wow thank you. That cleans up the code a lot and removes the use of defining a range. I really appreciate the help, this is going to save me a lot of time at work

Answer (score 0):

this is how to export a range  ... arrived at this by recording a macro, which ended up starting with `Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat` .... `Selection` is a range object .....

```
ActiveDocument.Range(800, 1000).ExportAsFixedFormat _
    OutputFileName:=strName & "PLAN.pdf", _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
    OpenAfterExport:=True, _
    OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
    ExportCurrentPage:=False, _
    Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
    IncludeDocProps:=False, _
    KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, _
    DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, _
    UseISO19005_1:=False
```

change first line to export 2nd section

```
    ActiveDocument.Sections(2).Range().ExportAsFixedFormat _
```

you can do this to see what will be exported  ... use for debugging, to see which range you are referrencing

```
ActiveDocument.Sections(2).Range().Select   ' you can instead paste this line into the "Immediate Window", and then look at your document
Stop
```

Comment: Thank you for the code above, I pasted it and tried it out, but had an extra page is being generated and my active fields in the document are not found in the exported document. I'm going to try using integers first with my first approach but will play with this one too. I'm new to this so it's all foreign to me. I appreciate your support!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you first select the section you want to export and then use `wdExportSelection` instead of `wdExportFromTo`. To select the section, see [this page](https://word.tips.net/T000523_Selecting_an_Entire_Section.html) where `Selection.Range.Sections.First.Range.Select` is used, or experiment with the macro recorder. But, if you do want to use `wdExportFromTo` then the answer to your question about "entering those strings as page numbers" is that, yes, you have the right idea, but you would need to use integers rather than strings.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried wdExportSelection but have been running into more problems. I'm going to investigate how I can assign the page numbers from sections as integers like you mentioned because that might work in the end. I get an extra page when I export the ExportSelection and my fields are blank in the exported document. (I have fields updating in the document) Thanks!

Comment: So I've been experimenting with entering the page numbers are integers and have figured out how to get the end of the section as an integer. I haven't been able to get the first value of the section range as an integer. I'm guessing it's pretty easy, would you know what that command might be? Below is what I added and intValue1 works for identifying the last page of the section. But I can't get inValue2 to identify the first page of the section.

Comment: <pre>Dim intValueR As Range
Dim intValue1 As Integer
Dim intValue2 As Integer
Set intValueR = ActiveDocument.Sections(3).Range
intValue1 = CStr(intValueR.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber))
intValue2 = ?? <code>

Comment: I added the code from the above post as an edit to my original post. The formatting makes it unreadable in my response.